# How can i Test my Apps on real devices?

Tags: testing, automation, manual-testing

I have developed app and i want test my app on real devices.

is there any tool to do both manual and automation testing for my app?

Comment: An app on what? ... and `real devices` means what: phone, tablet, PC ?

Comment: app functions. yes, phone and tablet.

Comment: James Refer my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dear Your requirement is not too clear for me But manually you have to use install app on multiple devices and test it, There are different websites which provide mobiles online to test application some are free and some have premium accounts

- pCloudy
- bitbar
- Experitest etc..

For automation you have to use tools like:

- Appium for Android and IOS
- Robotium for Android
- MonkeyTalk
- Selendroid for Android